# URL Rewriting from GridView in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, url-rewriting

I'm using Url Rewriting in my website.

I'm able to rewrite the url using

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("bills-show");
```

But from my GridView how can I redirect to another page ??
 Currently I'm using the following code in my `GridViewRowDataBound`.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='CallCenter/BillDetails.aspx?billNo=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
```

But what I need is using URL Rewriting.

I tried using

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "WriteUrl(" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + ")"); // in GridViewRowDataBound.
```

and

```
protected string WriteUrl(string billNo)
{
    return pg.GetRouteUrl("bill-details", new { billno = billNo });
}
```

but this is not working !!!

Can you help me out ???

Comment: How's your new URL going to look like?

Comment: `website.com/orders/127` here `127` is `billNo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HyperLinkField](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx&ei=zIObUNKjMorZ4QTD9oGoCA&usg=AFQjCNEbbcA9elILi_YM1nwDeQxqfH1new&sig2=ox2c8z9JWFZZDYqlphHpmw) in GridView columns list:

```
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Account" DataTextField="Account" 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="Account" Target="_blank" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CallCenter/BillDetails.aspx?billNo=n={0}"
    SortExpression="Account" HeaderStyle-Width="61" />
```

If this code works without rewriting:

```
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='CallCenter/BillDetails.aspx?billNo=" +
                              e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
```

Then this should be not a problem with:

```
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='"location='orders/" +
                              e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
```

Comment: Currently in my gridview when I click anywhere on the gridview row the page will be redirected. I want to retain the same process and apply the URL Rewriting..